# Change only text (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem that i cannot solve.I have  this : `<p>Text<span></span></p>` and i want to change only the text of the `<p>`.Which means, when i click on an change-Button, the text based on an input field should replace the text.
What i have tried is something like this : `$("p").text("newText")` but this will also remove the `<span>`.

So how can i only change the text and not the inner html...

Comment: Can you put the text in its own span, `<p><span id="theText">Text</span><span></span></p>` and then change the contents of `theText`?

Comment: Put "Text" in another span and change the text of that span

Comment: <span> need to have an ID or a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your HTML above you can do

```
$('p').contents().first()[0].textContent='newText';
```

The idea is to take advantage of the fact that [**contents()**](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) includes *text-nodes*. Then, access by index `[0]` to get the native javascript `DOM` element and set the `textContent`

```js
$('p').contents().first()[0].textContent = 'newText';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text<span>inside span</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put another `span` inside of the `p` tag and only change its contents:

```
<p>
  <span id="theText">Text</span>
  <span></span>
</p>
```

And then:

```
$('#theText').text('newText');
```

```js
$('#theText').text('newText')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <span id="theText"></span>
  <span>some other span</span>
</p>
```